# Can we track the user location without internet in IOS?

Tags: ios7

Actually i build the travel app which helps to track the user location but if there is no internet how can i store the location ?is there any trick to findout the location with GSM ?

Comment: ??? Locating the user does not need internet connection. You only need the GPS to be enabled.

Comment: Using GPS you will get the location(lat-lon) , but again how are you going to "track" the user without internet? You will need to send the location to someone else for being tracked right?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes It is very much possible but gets useless to you.

*You can get the approximate (lati & longi) position(if operator allows, I dont think they do) but what would you do because It wouldn't be possible to communicate back to traveler/user. At most you can do is send user SMS.*

Mobile network is consisting of up of a number of adjacent radio cells, each of which is characterized by an identifier made up of four data items:

1. Cell ID
2. LAC, or Local Area Code
3. MCC, an acronym for Mobile Country Code
4. MNC, or Mobile Network Code, which obviously identifies the phone company itself

For this reason, once a cell name and coordinates(latitude and longitude) are known, and considering the maximum distance allowed between this cell and a phone before the phone connects to a new cell, it is possible to find out, approximately, the most distant position of the phone itself.

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible to use GSM.GSM service providers can get the location details but they don't share those data to public.